# To Be Used Of/For

Tags: meaning, grammar, idioms, word-usage

Does "to be used OF" mean "to be used FOR":

> [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism)
>   The English term "empiric" derives from the Greek word ἐμπειρία, which is cognate with and translates to the Latin experientia, from which we derive the word "experience" and the related "experiment". The term ***was used of*** the Empiric school of ancient Greek medical practitioners, who rejected the doctrines of the (Dogmatic school), preferring to rely on the observation of "phenomena".

Or is it poor writing?

Comment: **Used of** is a phrase that describes words or phrases; it means "used to describe".  I'm having trouble Googling a reference because of the "of", but it's a standard phrase - not poor writing at all.  Perhaps a little old-fashioned.  It can also mean "used **by**" - there's an old hymn *Used of God* - but that's a different phrase.

Comment: It's poor writing, an attempted eruditicism.

Comment: Unless it's the AD 46 version of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 7):

It's more than usual looking to me, since like many here I'm often looking into what words where used *for*, I'm also looking at what they were used *of*, and hence encounter the use quite often.

Of the great many cases in [etymonline.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22used%20of%22%20site%3aetymonline.com) alone, a great many are exactly as used here.

Oxford have no qualms about using it:

> The word **was used of** Irish peasants dispossessed by English settlers and living as robbers, and extended to other marauders especially in the Scottish Highlands. ([Definition of Tory](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Tory)).

And nor do I.

To specifically address:

> Does "to be used OF" mean "to be used FOR":

The phrasing specifically reflects the relationship between a word and what it represents. If you agree with the comments above that it seems like a forced attempt to sound erudite, then you could use *for* or perhaps *about* or "to refer to".

I for one don't, so while it's not a phrasing I often find myself using (even here, when what words were used of is a particularly common topic), I won't shy from it, either.

Comment: I think the usages of the preposition "of" in "What is said of something?" and "What do you think of something?" are similar to that in "Some word is used of something".

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't go so far as to say *used of* is always an indicator of "poor writing", but as [this chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=term%20was%20used%20for,term%20was%20used%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows, it's very much a declining usage.

[image]

It's probably declined even more than the chart implies, since some of the more recent instances will be citing earlier texts. And if you compare US/UK usage in that link you'll see *used of* is at least twice as "unpopular" in the US (often a good indicator of where global usage is headed).

Obviously there's absolutely no issue of grammar involved here. It's essentially a stylistic choice, but arguably (assuming you're aware of the relative prevalences) if you *do* opt for the less common form people have more right to ask *"Why?".* If your answer is *"Because it sounds more erudite"* then probably *your* usage is indeed "poor writing", because *you're a poor writer* if you allow such considerations to affect your choice of phrasing.

For the record, I don't think it sounds particularly erudite. It's just a bit dated. But that may be because I'm a Brit, and [we still use it](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20term%20was%20used%20for,the%20term%20was%20used%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) much more than Americans.

Answer (score 2):

I'm American from south Louisiana and for me, "to be used of" means "to be used to." It used to annoy my ex when I said, "I'm used of annoying people." "I'm used of it" because I've become acclimated to and it no longer bothers me. Maybe I'm just weird, but I didn't see what he got so worked up about.

Comment: Well, that’s certainly interesting. I’ve never heard of such a thing before.